# Property should be @synthesize with inner var or not

Tags: objective-c, properties, xcode4.5, synthesize

I'm little confuse because in some tutorials is just

in h

```
@property (readwrite,nonatomic) NSUInteger DirectProp;
```

in m

```
@synthesize DirectProp;
```

But in other is like this

in h

```
@interface MyClass : CCNode {
    NSUInteger throuVarProp;

}
@property (readwrite,nonatomic) NSUInteger ThrouVarProp;
```

in m

```
@synthesize ThrouVarProp = throuVarProp;
```

Which way is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a single argument:

```
@synthesize directProp;
```

The synthesized getter/setter methods are called the same as the instance variable used to store the value.  This can get confusing.  For example:

```
self.directProp = YES;

[self setDirectProp:YES];

directProp = YES;
```

Are all valid.

With the additional `= ivar`, you are able to name the instance variable (the convention being to use a leading underscore), which is a good idea, so you don't get confused:

```
@synthesize directProp = _directProp;


self.directProp = YES;

[self setDirectProp:YES];

_directProp = YES;
```

As also mentioned, with newer runtimes you don't need to declare the instance variable before use, which is also a bad idea and seems to be there to promote laziness.  You will regret using this feature some day...

Comment: so you say that using iVar is good practice when my class will be called more than once in the time but when I use my class just once, dealloc it and once more alloc/init then I can pass that approach?

Comment: @BłażejWdowikowski I'm not sure I said that, but use the `@synthesize directProp = _directProp;` approach and declare your instance variables.

Answer (score 2):

**Both are correct...**

The difference is in older and newer style of writing.

In latest versions of Xcode you will see even `synthesize` is not required and it will take automatically as _yourIvarName

Answer (score 0):

They are both right.

With:

```
@interface MyClass : CCNode {
    NSUInteger throuVarProp;

}
```

You are saying to the compiler that that object has an **instance variable** of NSUInteger kind.
This if formally correct, but now this code is auto generated by Xcode and the compiler when you use a @property.

@syntesize, used in the implementation, creates the getter and setters: special instance methods used to access your instance variable from "outside".

In the last XCode (AFAIK from 4.4) even the @syntesize is auto generated, in the format

```
@syntesize var = _var;
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer runtimes don't require you to define the iVar. In fact, they even auto-synthesize the iVar for you.

```
// .h
@property (…) Type name;
```

This will automatically synthesize the property as if you had written:

```
// .m
@synthesize name = _name;
```

Thus you're even able to access the underlying variable, which I would not recommend though because I consider it an underlying implementation detail.

Note that if you override the getter the auto-synthesis will no longer happen:

```
// .m
@synthesize lazyProperty = _lazyProperty;
- (NSString *)lazyProperty {
    if (!_lazyProperty)
        _lazyProperty = @"Foobar";

    return _lazyProperty;
}
```